# Dynamic lm formula using data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data table to crunch through lots of linear models but I am not able to use the formula interface.
An example is below:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(grp = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b",10)),
                 x1 = rnorm(20),
                 x2 = rnorm(20),
                 y = rnorm(20))
n <- names(dt)
modFormula <- paste0("y ~ ", paste0(n[!n %in% c("y", "grp")], collapse = "+"))

#This gives me an error - Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
results <- dt[, as.list(coef(lm(modFormula))), by = .(grp)]

#This works but I ideally don't want to be typing out the variables manually
results <- dt[, as.list(coef(lm(y~x1+x2))), by = .(grp)]
```

How can I dynamically pass in the formula/ x,y variables?

I am churning through thousands of models and this is the fastest way I've found so far of doing it - any other suggesting are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use the `data` in `lm`

```
dt[, as.list(coef(lm(modFormula, data = .SD))), by = .(grp)]
#   grp (Intercept)         x1         x2
#1:   a   0.2185345 -0.7334866 -0.5986349
#2:   b   0.4499405 -0.5264809  0.1454797
```

Checking the output with the second approach

```
dt[, as.list(coef(lm(y~x1+x2))), by = .(grp)]
#   grp (Intercept)         x1         x2
#1:   a   0.2185345 -0.7334866 -0.5986349
#2:   b   0.4499405 -0.5264809  0.1454797
```